# Data type using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

If I ftp into a database and use pandas.read_sql to read in a huge file, what data type would the variable set equal to this be? And, if applicable, what kind of format would it be in? What object type is a pandas data frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Variable = ?**

The variable set would be equal to a `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` object.

**Format?**

The `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` format is a collection of numpy ndarrays, dicts, series, arrays or list-like structures that make up a 2 dimensional (typically) tabular data structure.

**Pandas Object Type?**

A `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` object is an organized collection of list like structures containing multiple data types.

Answer (score 0):

The function `pandas.read_sql` returns a DataFrame.

The `type` of a DataFrame in pandas is `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`.